# How to get Android Application to push notifications after ui thread is closed

Tags: android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast, notificationmanager

**How to get push notification working after manually closing UI on Android?**

Hi, I need some help, Couldn't find any solutions by searching.

Application basically is like any other messaging applications, ex. Whatsapp.

I have **MessageService** running **as own process**, even UI closed, it stays alive.

This is how my application basically works:

1. **MainActivity** start service
2. **MessageService** send broadCast to
3. **messageReceiver** gets broadCast and run messageLoader
4. **MessagesLoader** extends **AsyncTask** gets changes from database
5. **MessagesLoader** push notification.

Every these parts **working correctly** when **UI running**

When I close UI, messageService restarts again, but no push notifications after UI closed.

**Any help to get this work would be appreciated.**

**Thanks**

Here is some code snippet to understand how my thing works..

**MainActivity.java**

```
    ...........................
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);

        registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter(MessageService.MESSAGES_BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }
    ...........................
```

**MessageService.java**

```
public class MessageService extends Service {
    Updater updater;
    BroadcastReceiver messageBroadcaster;
    Intent intent;
    Context context;
    static final public String MESSAGES_BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.<Your Package>";

    public MessageService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        this.intent = intent;
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.updater = new Updater();
        this.context = getApplicationContext();
        this.intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (!updater.isRunning()) {
            updater.start();
            updater.isRunning = true;
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (updater.isRunning) {
            updater.interrupt();
            updater.isRunning = false;
            updater = null;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    class Updater extends Thread {

        public boolean isRunning = false;
        public long DELAY = 2500;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning) {
                sendResult();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return this.isRunning;
        }
    }

    public void sendResult() {
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**MessageReceiver.java**

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MessageService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
        new MessagesLoader(context).execute();
    }
}
```

**MessageLoader.java**

```
public class MessagesLoader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    public MessagesLoader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.intent = new Intent(this.context, ChatsActivity.class);
        this.prev_count = prev_count;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatsActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);


        this.mBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("YOUR APP");
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://yourURL.com/get_data.php");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

            con.setDoOutput(true);

            String urlParameters = "<OWN PARAMETERS>";
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            con.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            return new String(result);
        } catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        initData(result);
    }

    public void initData(String result) {
        // Actually Store Data to sharedPreferences
        String error = "";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        // ...ETC

        int count = 5;
        showNotification(5);
    }


    public void showNotification(int count) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this.context, ChatsActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, 0, mIntent, 0);

        Intent cIntent = new Intent(this.context, NotificationActionService.class);
        PendingIntent cPIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this.context, 0, cIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigTextStyle.bigText("YOUR BIG TEXT");
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContentText("YOUR CONTENT TEXT")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(R.color.white, 1000, 500)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setGroup("YOUR GROUP")
            .setTicker("YOUR TICKER TEXT")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setCategory("YOUR CATEGORY")

             .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
             .addAction(0, "Show Messages", pIntent);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yourpackage" >
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourpackage.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.yourpackage.MessageService"
        android:process=":messageService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/messageService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.yourpackage.MessageService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.MessageReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.yourpackage.MessageReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Now my application is always showing me new messages info even without UI running.

**Here is solution to fix this problem.**

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onresume();

    serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);

    /* COMMENTED OUT LINE BELOW */
    //registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter(MessageService.MESSAGES_BROADCAST_ACTION));
}
```

**MessageService.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    updater = new Updater();
    context = getApplicationContext();

    /* AND ADDED THAT LINE HERE AND */
    registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter(MESSAGES_BROADCAST_ACTION));
    intent = new Intent(MESSAGES_BROADCAST_ACTION);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Message Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```